# How do I configure the initial settings for web study with clone coding?

Tags: intellij-idea, development-environment

How do I configure the initial settings for web study with clone coding?

I chose a repository open on github for studying jsp.
And I cloned using git and opened the project with intellij.
However, even if I run it with tomcat, the page behaves strangely.
Perhaps the initial setting in the development environment is wrong.
I am wondering if there is any way to reliably solve these initial setup problems.

Comment: What error do you get?